# C: Wrong matrix values when printing them in main()

Tags: arrays, c, function, matrix

I have a function that creates a new matrix based on dimensions given by the user, it looks like this:

```
void matrix(n, m){

    int mtx[n][m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {

            if ((j == 1 && i != 0 && i != n - 1) || (i == 1 && j != 0 && j < m - 3) ||
                (i == n - 2 && j != 0 && j < m - 3) || (j == m - 4 && i != 0 && i != n - 1)) {

                mtx[i][j] = 1;
                printf("%d ", mtx[i][j]);
            }
            else {
                mtx[i][j] = 0;
                printf("%d ", mtx[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

It outputs something like this (for the dimensions 13x13 as an example):

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

But if I try to do the same in main(), something like this is the output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 7602432 0 0 0 0 0 -13856 
0 0 0 0 0 -2145891403 1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 
-2144601408 1 -13360 0 1 0 64 0 0 0 -2145133264 1 -13168 
0 -12816 0 0 0 0 0 231600 8 0 0 -13168 0 
-12816 0 -2145990936 1 15 0 3 0 4206656 1 50 0 -2145996184 
1 -13904 0 18 0 -2145970054 1 2 0 -2145145120 1 -2144661632 1 
-2145988848 1 0 0 -2144002969 0 0 0 0 0 -2145996184 1 -13808 
0 0 0 -2145968555 1 -2145969808 1 -13808 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 -2147184784 1 -2145147008 1 -2145968503 1 102 0 48 0 4202496 
1 0 0 -2147184784 1 0 0 5624 0 -10624 0 -2145503066 1 
-2145147008 1 0 0 0 0 -13168 0 -12816 0 0 0 0 
0 -13312 0 -2145650929 1 0 0 -2145145672 1 4206712 1 -13416 0 
0 0 688 0 13 0 4199690 1 13 1 13 0 -13360
```

This is the piece of code I'm using inside main to output this matrix:

```
    int mtx[t1][t2];
    matrix(t1, t2);

    for (int i = 0; i < t1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < t2; j++) {
            printf("%d ", mtx[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

My objective is to have the right values stored on the mtx[t1][t2] defined in main.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You never set the values in `mtx`.

Comment: You have two different and distinct and totally unrelated  variables named `mtx`. Please take some time to go back to your text-book and read more about *scopes*.

Comment: @dbush you mean the dimensions? ("t1" and "t2")

Comment: The local variable `mtx` inside the `matrix()` function is not the same as the variable in `main()`.

Comment: @Tastefool I mean `mtx` is not modified in any way.  As the other comments have said, `mtx` in `main` and `mtx` in `matrix` are two different variables.

Comment: Instead of showing fragments "like" your code, you should create a [mcve] that unambiguously shows how to reproduce your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated, the `mtx` array in the main function, despite having the same name, is completely unrelated with the `mtx` array inside the function, they belong in different scopes and one is not aware of the other, in order to modify the main function `mtx` array inside the function you must pass it as a parameter, something like this:

```
// add a parameter of the same type to the function parameter list
void matrix(int n, int m, int mtx[][m])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if ((j == 1 && i != 0 && i != n - 1) || (i == 1 && j != 0 && j < m - 3) ||
                (i == n - 2 && j != 0 && j < m - 3) || (j == m - 4 && i != 0 && i != n - 1))
            {
                mtx[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                mtx[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

```
int main()
{
    int t1 = 13, t2 = 13;
    int mtx[t1][t2];

    matrix(t1, t2, mtx); // pass it as an argument

    for (int i = 0; i < t1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < t2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", mtx[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

You'll need to remove the declaration of `mtx` in the function to avoid a redeclaration error.

Comment: I was working on that solution, the only error that I was making now was that when, in main, I was passing it as an argument I was using the variable name with its dimensions as well, so the program wasn't outputing nothing, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Tastefool, yes, that's it, the dimensions are not part of the argument, I'm glad you solved it.

Comment: @anastaciu is it considered to be a bad style to do  mtx[i][j] = (j == 1 && i != 0 && i != n - 1) || (i == 1 && j != 0 && j < m - 3) ||
                (i == n - 2 && j != 0 && j < m - 3) || (j == m - 4 && i != 0 && i != n - 1); ?

Comment: @dreamcrash, that's... quite a line of code, let's just leave at that. ;)